# Asynchronous Javascript loading with extjs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, extjs, dom-events

I am using ExtJS framework for a widget. I have written a embedd.js script, that asynchronously loads ext-all.js  (combined with other javascript).  Finally, it attaches a function to be called for Ext.onReady

However, it does not get called at all using this mechanism. If however, I load the all.js  and the css in the  element of the page,  remaining all things being equal, it works.

How do I solve this?

The code can be seen on:

```
http://38.109.218.86/cw/works.php

http://38.109.218.86/cw/does_not_work.php
```

(Not that I am trying to load extjs code itself asynchronously here, so it loads after rest of the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing a JS error in your not working example

```
Line 78: Ext.onReady()
```

If you are loading ExtJS async, then you can only do something like `Ext.onReady()` *after* the library has loaded.

Comment: How do I call Ext.onReady() *after* the library has loaded? appendChild I think will just modify the DOM, whats the event for the library actually getting loaded? Thanks